# Cannot access own resources from androidTest after importing own library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have my own java library and an app for testing it.

Somehow I cannot access test-app resources (R.navigation.nav_graph) from

`test-app/androidTest`, but can access it from activities and fragments in the test-app.

I am importing the library in Gradle using:

```
implementation project(':ownlibrary')
```

Changing to:

```
androidTestImplementation project(':ownlibrary')
```

allows me to access resources in `test-app/androidTest` but disables the access from activities and fragments of the test-app.

How can I correctly access resources of the test-app from `test-app/androidTest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an `applicationId` in the Gradle file of the test-app.

I used `com.example.ownlibrary` instead of `com.example.testapp`